Sitecore SXA Where is Promo layout located
I am using OOTB Promo rendering in Sitecore SXA and need to customize some design , but not able to find the layout for this rendering on filesystem.


If you want to customize the layout of Promo component it is good to create a rendering varaint and style/make changes accordingly.
But still if you need to change the view or HTML structure of the Promo component you can navigate to inetpub\wwwroot\<your-instance-name>\Views\Variants and make changes accordingly.
Remember to add the view in your project so whenever you publish the project the view file gets automatically updated

The code for the Promo is not on the file system. The promo uses a Rendering Variant for its definition. This may be a Scriban template or an Item template that is stored in the Rendering Variant definition item for your site.
You can find the item under: /sitecore/content/<SXA Tenant>/<SXA Site>/Presentation/Rendering Variants/Promo/<variant name>
It should have a default version, you can customize that or create new variants as needed.
The documentation on the OOTB Promo component can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/add-a-promo-rendering.html
Documentation on how to use Rendering Variants can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/103/sitecore-experience-accelerator/rendering-variants.html

To customize the layout of the Promo component, create a rendering variant and adjust styling as needed. For altering the HTML structure, navigate to inetpub\wwwroot\<instance-name>\Views\Variants\Promo.cshtml.

You can find the View file for Promo component inside the following location:
/Views/Variants/Promo.cshtml

Since the above component loops through Variant Fields to create the component inside View file, you can find the html structure in the below location, that gets wrapped in the above view file.
/sitecore/content/<Tenant>/<Site>/Presentation/Rendering Variants/Promo/Default


More details can be found on below article, that explains how to build the component that uses rendering variants.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/build-a-rendering-that-includes-variants.html
Hope this helps!!!
